# Is it a good idea to set code the viewController subclass on several files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I made a big program. This is the kind of header I used:

```
@interface:BGDetailBusinessViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate,BGDetailFooterViewProtocol,BGDetailPhotoCell,PageControlDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,BGShareSocialDelegate,BGReviewControllerProtocol>
```

I think the code smell. That one file `BGDetailBusinessViewController.m` is responsible to handle too many things.

What's the normal pattern to remove the smell?

Are there some sample open source code of big Objective-C codes? That way we can all see how the pro is doing when they make really really really large program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - in the model view controller pattern (MVC), the job of the controller is to act as 'glue' between the model and the view. It should therefore not contain a lot of code, and the code it does contain is responsible for mediating between the view and the model.

If you're using interface builder, it can be easy to end up with a lot of code in your controller. It's possible to avoid this, but my suggestion is to use code-based views, for more complex work.

- These views should use composition - look for reusable collections of UI elements and build them as discrete classes. Build your views from these.
- Create your own delegate protocols to shunt data between your views and the model. Typically the controller will be the concrete realization of the delegate, but if its a large concern you can use a separate class, and provide this as a member of the view controller (dependency injection).
- Use Object Orientation to create a rich model.
- If it really does make sense to have a single large class, encapsulate related pieces using categories.

In your specific case, why not have the view act as the UITableViewDelegate and data source, simply providing a method to pass it the required data? This would be more true to the MVC design pattern.

Comment: if the view act as the UITableViewDelegate, then the view becomes it's own controller. I like the idea though. In IOS5, we can nest view Controller anyway. Good. Know any LARGE sample code?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't mention view controller containment. This was also possible prior to IOS5, but the life cycle management was a bit trickier - no willMoveTo. . . convenience methods. . ManiacDev website maintains a list of open-source full applications - might help.